# Python - Django [error 404 page not found urls]

Tags: python, django, url, view

I have written the following simple piece of code, I just wanted to check whether when accessed the POST method, it says 405, but instead it says page not found.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import helloform

def index(request):
    form = helloform()
    return render(request, 'hello/index.html', {'form' : form})

def addintodb(request): #trying to invoke this function
    form = helloform(request.POST)
    print(request.POST)
    return redirect(index)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('add', views.addintodb, name='addtodb'), #using this url
]
```

index.html

```
> form action="{% url 'addtodb' %}" method="POST" role="form" # from here
>     ...                      
>     </form>
```

I figured quite after some time that, having my projects URL to "" gives the required. (i.e.)

myproject's urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('hello.urls')) #previously I had path('hellobfs', include('hello.urls'))
]
```

so removing any path of my project's url allowed me to have myapp's url working without "404" error, can someone explain why?

Comment: 405 doesn't mean it's successful.

Comment: but it should actually say 405, method not allowed when I try to access hellobfs/add. and those ' * ' are placed for marking the lines as bold in Stackoverflow,

Comment: Please format your code properly. In Python it's essential, and we may not understand it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this, as the urls.py in my app requires both the urls of projects and app

that is 
project url ->

```
path('hellobfs', include('hello.urls'))
```

app's url ->

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('adding', views.addnewentry, name='add'),
```

when I need to traverse to adding page, I need to provide (where I made the mistake)

```
127.0.0.1:8000/hellobfsadding
```

which provided the method not allowed, and to improve readability we can add a '/' in project's url like

```
path('hellobfs/', include('hello.urls'))
```

now we can traverse by

```
127.0.0.1:8000/hellobfs/adding
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save your form in your views.py file try adding a ,    form.save() after your ,     form = helloform(request.POST)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `return redirect(index)` with `return redirect('/', )`. Your code should look like this:

```
def addintodb(request): #trying to invoke this function
    form = helloform(request.POST)
    print(request.POST)
    return redirect('/', )  #<-- this is the url pattern for your index
```

Comment: but it doesn't enters the function at all, faced with 404 page not found error, please explain where i am going wrong in Url part